# From where can I get learning resources for three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am just trying my hands at three.js. This is the link:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/

But there seems to be no documentation for this and rightly so because it is developed by a small(but genius) team. There are loads of examples when you download it however without basic explanation it doesn't make much sense to just start looking at code. I found few tutorials at:

http://aerotwist.com/

But it's just few. Just explains 3-4 concepts here and there.

Is there any other documentation or good tutorial sites for this library? Video screencasts, tutorials or even book anything will be do. If some book is available then it will be best but I don't think any is available.

Comment: You mentioned the main site, but still, http://www.aerotwist.com/lab/ looks like it's as good as it gets, tutorial-wise.

Comment: @John: The main site has no documentation just 100's of examples with tons of codes of source code. I am not that good at directly starting with the code without understanding what the library offers and it's concepts. Aerotwist is good but I need comprehensive guide  to know what the library offers not just an overview. I am sure three.js has much more to offer than shown on aerotwist.

Comment: im willing to write doc to help people using three.js. can you give some hint on the kind of stuff you would like to be documented ? stuff like screencast are easy to do ? would they fit your need ? i was thinking about google hangout session. i dunno. in short i am ok to devote time but not sure how to use it efficiently. help me help you :) ps: i asked this question before but the post deleted because i gave a link. Not sure why. i may have been confused for a spammer or something. so i retry and no link in this one :)

Comment: I know you posted your blog link here. But you are new here(which is evident from your points ;) so SO may have mistook you for spammer. Anyways, I have enough points and I don't think and there is no chance it will take my for spammer. Here is Jerome's site link:  http://learningthreejs.com/

Comment: Now, back to the point. Yes screencasts would be an awesome way to get your points across to newbies in three.js. I will appreciate that you explain how things work, I mean just a basic explanation of why things work that way rather than just making us cram the methods and classes without really knowing how it works because if you do that the followers will be able to understand the demo when they themselves need to create something on their own, they won't be able because they don't have the understanding itself. Also if the screencasts take too long to make it I (we are) am also OK with..

Comment: tutorials given that there are sufficient adequate comments such that newbies can understand it but my advise to you would be to make screencasts only initially because physics stuff such dot product etc are not understood directly by reading. For eg. if you read this link: http://aerotwist.com/lab/an-introduction-to-shaders-part-2/ and read the part "faking light" it's not intuitive what is modelViewMatrix and what is projectionMatrix and how dot product fakes the light. I want you explain all these details rather than "just accepting".

Comment: I don't want to you to go deep dive into physics and leave the basic intention of explaining three.js but little explanation of how things work is always desirable. I hope you will take my points into consideration.

Comment: P.S: I've read your twitter status about your cry for your 1st answer getting deleted. It's the way SO works. As you have more points, you will get more and more rights. I have voted you answer(given 10 points).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some more learning resources here:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki

Comment: doob: Are there any possibilities that a book will be published on how to use three.js? I will be the 1st one to purchase it;)

Comment: Besides me writing it, everything is possible ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on creating a set of examples at:
http://github.com/stemkoski/Three.js-examples

Answer (score 2):

There is a udacity course "Interactive 3D Graphics" that uses three.js as the vehicle to teach about 3D graphics. It covers most of the concepts available in three js. It also has in browser programming exercises that allow the user to try out the concepts and get feedback. The quizzes are not as valuable, though; testing mostly on niche, not core, concepts.

https://www.udacity.com/course/cs291

Answer (score 1):

The freenode channel #three.js is quite lively. You may try there for live help. irc://irc.freenode.net/#three.js

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of examples and links on reddit, they may be helpful.

[Reddit three.js community](http://www.reddit.com/r/threejs/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a book available now (since 17th of October 2013) from packt. Full disclaimer, I'm the author :) A bit late since the question was asked a long time ago, but it's good to have an overview of learning materials for Three.js.

The book can be found here: [http://www.amazon.com/Learning-Three-js-JavaScript-Library-WebGL/dp/1782166289/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1382358877&sr=8-1&keywords=learning+three.js](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1782166289)